# Lombok + JPA Canonical Metamodel generation: is it possible?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, lombok, jpamodelgen

- I'm using [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/), a ([spurious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107197/how-does-lombok-work)) [JSR 269](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=269) implementation providing useful features like the generation of getters and setters **at compile time** while keeping the source code clean:

  ```
  @Getter @Setter private String foo;
  ```
- I'd like to use another annotation processor (a [JSR 269](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=269) implementation like [`hibernate-jpamodelgen`](http://hibernate.org/orm/tooling/)) to [generate the JPA Canonical Metamodel](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html) ([JSR 317](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/summary?id=317)), but no matter how hard I try (Maven, Eclipse, etc...) it does seem that there is no way to instruct it to start reading the entities from the *generated* code, instead that from the source (that, being not yet interpreted by Lombok, does not even compile).

Is there a way to pipe the two annotation processors in the way needed?

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29193806/1743880) is about the same problem (ordering of annotation processors).

Comment: I actually have no idea if it is solvable or not (just read the target post). But, I think this should be closed as duplicate of the other question, do you agree?

Comment: @Tunaki I think that this question is not duplicate of [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29193806/specifying-order-of-annotation-processors). I can suggest a solution for _this_ question: add `@Access(AccessType.FIELD)` annotation for entity class. But it not suitable for _that_ question.

Comment: The solution to this post worked for me: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602317/cant-build-maven-jhipster-project-with-lombok

Comment: Thank you for posting your comment here, @NDierauf!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to configure your build to first run [delombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok.html) on your source files and compile the rest later.

Disclosure: I am a lombok developer.

Comment: Thank you. Could you expand a bit about its usage ? It seems (at least for the Maven plugin) that I should move all my Lombok-annotated Java files from `src/main/java` to `src/main/lombok`, but I'm still not sure how nor why the second annotation processor should find the delomboked files, since my entities (from which the metamodel would be generated) *are* Lombok-annotated and hence would be in `src/main/lombok`. As it seems, it could work to separate Lombok files and make other AP work on the non-lombok files, but does it work for Lombok annotated files too ? Sorry if I'm not clear enough

Comment: You don't need to separate the lomboked files from the non-lomboked files. Delombok is capable of handling non-lomboked files as well. I am not familiar with the maven plugin myself. However, it could by that by default is processes the `src/main/lombok` directory, but I expect that that's configurable.