# Can't build maven jhipster project with lombok

Tags: maven, jhipster, lombok

./mvnw and mvn clean install fail when adding lombok dependency but run successfully when launched from Intellij IDE
Find the error below :

```
INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] src/main/java/web/rest/core/service/impl/ProductServiceImpl.java:[18,29] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method builder()
  location: class com.test.one.web.rest.core.model.Product
```

Here is the POJO

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Builder
public class Product {
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other annotation processors explicitly listed in your pom file?

Comment: I would check if you are using the latest Lombok version, they changed something to work better with other annotation processors (for mapstruct i think) not so long time ago. On the other hand I would check if you have the lombok plugin for your IntelliJ, but normally then the maven build would work and the IDE build not... ^^

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The maven project Jhipster generated uses a annotationProcessorPaths in the maven compile plugin, that's why it cannot look up the latest lombok unless we specify lombok as one of the annotation processor.

Working code is as followed.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
<configuration>
    <annotationProcessorPaths>
        <path>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </path>
        <!-- For JPA static metamodel generation -->
        <path>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </path>
        <path>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.18</version>
        </path>
    </annotationProcessorPaths>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to work with the following combination of versions:

- maven-compiler-plugin: 3.3
- lombok: 1.16.18 (latest)

So for example, a pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <version>1.16.18</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

...

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3</version>
</plugin>
```