# Dagger 2 using classes generated by another library

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, kapt

I have a homemade library that generates DataMapper classes.

They are generated with `@Singleton` and `@Inject` annotations to be able to inject them where i need them.

But where it doesn't work is when Dagger tries to create the dependency tree, this error shows :

```
:data:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin
e: /Users/me/myproject/data/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/myproject/data/di/DataComponent.java:11: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] error.NonExistentClass cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract com.myproject.domain.repository.ContentRepository contentRepository();
                                                                      ^
  error.NonExistentClass is injected at
      com.myproject.data.repository.ContentDataRepository.<init>(…, myGeneratedDataMapper, …)
  com.myproject.data.repository.ContentDataRepository is injected at
      com.myproject.data.di.module.DataModule.contentRepository(contentDataRepository)
  com.myproject.domain.repository.ContentRepository is provided at
      com.myproject.data.di.DataComponent.contentRepository()
:data:kaptDebugKotlin
:data:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
```

Involved classes are :

DataModule (module for dagger)

```
@Module
class DataModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun contentRepository(contentDataRepository: ContentDataRepository): ContentRepository = contentDataRepository
}
```

DataComponent (component for dagger):

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [DataModule::class])
interface DataComponent {
    fun contentRepository(): ContentRepository
}
```

ContentDataRepository

```
@Singleton
class ContentDataRepository @Inject constructor(
        private val myGeneratedDataMapper: MyGeneratedDataMapper
) : ContentRepository {
    ...
}
```

MyGeneratedDataMapper

```
@Singleton
class MyGeneratedDataMapper @Inject constructor() {
   ...
}
```

The thing is, if i disable kapt of dagger dependency in `gradle.build`, then build, then enable it, then build, it works.

If i do a clean + build, it doesn't work, same error.
I want to make it work in one row.

Comment: I would guess that you might have a problem with timing I think for some reason dagger is executed before your class

Comment: It's exactly that, if you look closely at the gradle tasks order, `kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin` is where dagger wants to access to my generated class, while my class is generated is the `kaptDebugKotlin` task i guess

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. how are you importing dagger to your processor, and if  you don't import yourself then are you counting on the user to implement it?

Comment: I don't import the processor in my lib, so yes I let the user (me) implements it in the final project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using AS3.2 or AS3.3 with androidX artifacts or not but Maybe this is the case with you too.

so when i migrated to `androidX artifacts` in AS3.2 i got hit with bunch of `NonExistentClass` errors ends the build with

```
kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin 
:data:kaptDebugKotlin
:data:kaptDebugKotlin
```

I finally found out that it has something to do with Dagger itself and degraded the version from `2.17` to `2.16` now the latest version of Dagger2 is `2.18` which i can't use due to this bug / feature [they forgot about].

**Update:**

i found the solution and it just came today so here is the issue tracker link:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115738511

so the bug was not in the Dagger but it was with Jetifier and i totally ignored the fact that it was set enabled during migration

**here's the solution i copied from the link:**

> Sorry jetifier beta01 was not binary compatible with alpha10.
>
> We have published beta02 that should fix this issue.
>
> Please try:

```
buildscript {    dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta02'    } }
```

Answer (score -1):

You're probably not going to like my answer but the order is kinda random.
Look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29193806/specifying-order-of-annotation-processors) for some more explaining and maybe some more guidance but, if you want to verify you are running first look at Gradle plugins and how to use them